# sync/async insert or update ElasticSearch in Python

Tags: elasticsearch-py

I'm using ElasticSearch bulk Python API, Does it provide both sync and Async api?

Comment: using `refresh=True` with the query Derlin suggested got me the sync behavior I was expecting:  `helpers.bulk(es, insert_actions, refresh=True)`  This is on elasticsearch version 1.7.5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If by `sync` you mean a blocking operation**

In Python, the `bulk` functions are synchronous. The easiest way to go it through the [helper](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html?highlight=bulk#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk)

```
elasticsearch.helpers.bulk(client, actions, stats_only=False, **kwargs)
```

it returns a tuple with summary informations. It is thus synchronous.

**If by `sync` you mean consistency**

From the [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html):

> When making bulk calls, you can require a minimum number of active shards in the partition through the consistency parameter

In python, the [`bulk` function](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html?highlight=bulk#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.bulk) has a `consistency` parameter, allowing you to explicit how many shards must have acknowledged the change for the method to return.

**If by `timeout` you mean a way to stop the operation after a while**

If you need to limit the duration of a bulk operation, again the low level `bulk()` function is your friend. It takes a `timeout` parameter to add an explicit operation timeout.

Even more generally,

> Global timeout can be set when constructing the client (see Connection‘s timeout parameter) or on a per-request basis using request_timeout (float value in seconds) as part of any API call

For example:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
# only wait for 1 second, regardless of the client's default
es.cluster.health(wait_for_status='yellow', request_timeout=1)
```

---

As a side note, I searched for the `bulk()` call in java and especially the `bulk().await()`. I couldn't find anything. May I ask you for your source ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer, just a quick following question, does read() function has consistency, I didn't see the parameter, but I know it should be a number? say, just return one shard as read successful, or need to return quorum/all shards just as successful read.

Comment: For read operations, consistency is somewhat controlled by the preference parameter. From the docs: specify the node or shard the operation should be performed on (default: random). For more info, have a look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080808/get-consistency-and-quorum-in-elasticsearch. Hope it helps.