# How do I write to ElasticSearch with immediate consistency?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to have ElasticSearch commit my documents to index with immediate availability, meaning I am using ES as a database and I would like and further search requests to return the freshest data.

I have no issues with writing slower in order to achieve this, I am aware that this is not the intended use of ES but I need it for a toy project.

In essence, I am looking for something like a MySQL row lock on the index, or immediate flush to disk and memory once the document is inserted.

Speed is not an issue in my project. right now I am achieving this by waiting 200ms after an insert documents loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET Consistency (and Quorum) in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080808/get-consistency-and-quorum-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0):

When you're indexing, enable the `refresh` setting see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-refresh.html).
If you're indexing multiple documents at a time, you can invoke the `_refresh` [endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) at the end.
Both of options have a very important impact on performance (write flush, cache invalidation and so forth).

Comment: You can append ?preference=_primary to the url to ignore replicas: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html

Comment: The part about the replicas in the answer is not correct — the docs explicitly state: "Refresh the relevant primary and replica shards (not the whole index) immediately". If you can, do a `refresh=wait_for`; it will save you from unnecessary merges.

Comment: Removed the replica part